# Repeating Pattern Down Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe and am trying to repeat a pattern down two columns, X and Y. The pattern is as follows:

```
| df1  |  X  |  Y  |
|:---- |:---:|----:|
|  0   |  0  |  0  |
|  1   |  0  |  n  |
|  2   |  0  | 2n  |
|  3   |  0  | 3n  |
|  4   |  0  | 4n  |
|  ... | ... | ... |
|  r   |  0  | rn  |

|  r+1 |  n  |  0  |
|  r+2 |  n  |  n  |
|  r+3 |  n  | 2n  |
|  r+4 |  n  | 3n  |
|  r+5 |  n  | 4n  |
|  ... | ... | ... |
| 2r   |  n  | rn  |

| 2r+1 | 2n  |  0  |
| 2r+2 | 2n  |  n  |
| 2r+3 | 2n  | 2n  |
| 2r+4 | 2n  | 3n  |
| 2r+5 | 2n  | 4n  |
|  ... | ... | ... |
| 3r   | 3n  | rn  |
```

I am trying to have the pattern repeat down the X and Y columns after a certain number of rows are printed, represented by the variable r. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def setter(r, n, x): # x in your example is 2 because of 2n in X
    data = pd.DataFrame({
        "df1": np.arange(0,(x + 1)*r, r),
        "X": n * np.arange(x + 1),
    }).values
    data = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(data, r + 1, axis=0))
    data[0] += data.groupby(0).cumcount()
    data = data.rename(columns={0: "df1", 1: "X"})
    data["Y"] = np.repeat(np.arange(0, r + 1), x + 1) * n
    return data
setter(4,10, 2)
```